# How to sort the string number in descending order?

Tags: java, string, numbers, comparator

Below is my list which will always be in the form of `bXXXX` -

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("b5", "b10", "b2", "b1", "b40");
System.out.println(data);
```

My `data` list will always have strings in the form of `bXXXX`

Now I need to sort my above lists in descending order and extract the largest string from it..

So in the above example, it will be `b40`.. So below is the comparator I am using which sorts everything in ascending order -

```
static final Comparator<String> aStringComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        //assumed input are strings in the form axxxx
        int numfromS1 = Integer.valueOf(s1.subSequence(1, s1.length()).toString());
        int numfromS2 = Integer.valueOf(s2.subSequence(1, s2.length()).toString());
        return numfromS1 - numfromS2;
    }
};
```

And I am not able to understand how do I make this to sort it out in descending order so that I can extract the first index from the list which will be greatest string number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your comparator works in ascending order, then all you need to do is to invert the result of your comparator.

If this code works for you:

```
return numfromS1 - numfromS2;
```

then change it to:

```
return numfromS2 - numfromS1;
```

or, maybe to the little more idiomatic:

```
return (numfromS2 < numfromS1) ? -1: (numfromS2 > numfromS1) ? 1 : 0;
```

and now your data is going to be in descending order.

You could also, as suggested by others, use either:

```
return ((Integer) numfromS2).compareTo(numfromS1);
```

or:

```
Collections.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder(aStringComparator));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(1));
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(1));
            return Integer.compare(n2, n1);
        }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to sort in descending order -

```
Collections.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder(aStringComparator));
```

Answer (score 0):

def Descending_Order(num):                  > #  num = 18902

```
l = list(map(int, str(num)))            >  # [1, 8, 9, 0, 2]

r = sorted(l,reverse=True)              > # [9, 8, 2, 1, 0]

ch_r = map(str, r)                      > # ['9', '8', '2', '1','0']

num_r =''.join(ch_r)                    > # '98210'

return int(num_r)                       > # 98210
```

Comment: The question was tagged with `java`, which means that this is not helpful to the asker.